# do while and switch error

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

The error is when I run the program and type `n` to end choosing 
it doesn't end and keeps repeating the first `cout` and the default value:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    float y,result=0,paid,change;
    do {
        cout<<"enter another choose or press (n/N) to end choosing ";
        cin>>x;
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                int a=5;    
                cout<<"enter the wighte you want in (Kg) : ";
                cin>>y;
                result=a*y;
                break;}
        default:
            cout<<"wrong choooose "<<endl;
        }

    }
    while (x='n');
    cout<<"your total= "<<result<<endl;
    cout<<"mony value paid = ";
    cin>>paid;
    change =paid-result;
    cout<<"the change = "<<change<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want n to end it, you forgot a ! (assuming you meant to make it a character, since that's what you're reading). You also output that both n and N are valid, but imagine the user's confusion when N doesn't work!

Comment: ive added the ! but it also not working and forget about the N i just want to use the n

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `x` is an *integer*, which you then compare to a character literal.

This works well when using old C-style standard I/O, which uses `int` instead of `char`, but doesn't work in C++ where the types are distinct. This means that the input on the line

```
cin>>x;
```

will fail if you do not enter a valid integer.

Change the type of `x` to `char` and it should work.

There is also the problem with the assignment instead of the condition inside `while`.

Comment: @SmiLe... Because then `x` is a `char` and not an integer. You can use `case '1':` if you want `x` to be able to contain any character. This won't work for multi-digit numbers if you want to add those in the future though, so you may want to rethink how to handle input. ([`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) might help you there. Remember to check the result of the input operation!)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I totally missed that you're using C++ I/O here.

You declare `x` as an `int`, yet you enter the character literal `'n'`. The conversion will fail with C++ I/O streams, so `x` is never set. Don't confuse your data types; if you want to read a `char` then read a `char`, same for `int`.

Try something like this instead:

```
int x = 0;
do {
    if(!(cin >> x)) {
        cout << "enter a valid number" << endl;
        // clear fail flag
        cin.clear();      
        // consume newline
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    } else {
        // your logic here
    }
} while( x != -1 );
```

---

```
while (x='n');
```

That is not a comparison, it is an assignment, and the character `'n'` when converted to an integer will always evaluate to `true`, so your loop never ends.

Your next problem will be that you want to exit the loop when the input *is* `'n'`, not the other way around, so it should be...

```
while(x != 'n');
```

Also realize that, if the user enters `110`, the loop will exit.  `x` is an `int`, and the integral value of the character literal `'n'` is `110`. It will also fail for `'N'`.

Comment: @SmiLe...: Sorry, I totally missed that you're using C++ IO here.  You declare x as an int, yet you enter the character literal 'n'.  The conversion will fail with C++ IO streams, so x is never set.  Don't confuse your data types; if you want to read a char then read a char, same for int.

Comment: ok i noticed that too but how can i do it when typing n finish the loop

Comment: @SmiLe...: The simple solution would be to use some other integral value to signal that you are done, i.e., -1.